# Are the Klingon gods in Stovokor?

Tags: star-trek, klingon, religion

In the *Deep Space Nine* episode *Homefront*, Worf says:

> Our gods are dead. Ancient Klingon warriors slew them a millennia ago.  They were more trouble than they were worth.

So were they sent to Stovokor?  If not, do we ever find out what happened to the Klingon gods when they were killed?

Comment: He actually said "a millennia ago"? Or did he say something grammatical like "slew them millennia ago" or "a millennium ago"?

Comment: @user14111 : In the episode, it sounds definitely like Worf says "a millennia ago", and chakoteya (http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/483.htm) records it that way, too.  Considering that Kahless forged the Empire around 1400 years prior to *DS9* and Kahless himself now purportedly guards the Klingon afterlife, Worf probably meant "about a millennium ago".

Comment: Yes, I had noticed he said "a millennia" instead of "a millennium" and listened to a YouTube clip several times to be sure.  I think you're probably on target - I'm just waiting to see if we hear from someone who knows all things esoteric about Klingon religion.  (But I doubt anyone knows that much and I suspect the line was written without planning the full context of where it was set.)

Comment: The book the Klingon Art of War tells the legend of Klingons killing their gods in more detail, and state it happened before Kahless's time, though it could be just a continuity screw-up because of two different writers. I got the impression that the Klingon Gods had no afterlife, but that's just speculation.

Comment: @Nu'Daq: Who wrote the book and how close to canon is it?

Comment: @Tango: Klingon Art of War is written by Kieth R.A. DeCandido. Memory Alpha referred to it as a liscenced Star Trek work- does that count as canon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Stovokor***, the Klingon afterlife, is often referred to in *DS9* and *Voyager* as:

- a place for "the honoured dead"
- a destination for "true warriors" who, after crossing the River of Blood, pass through the Gates of Stovokor (guarded by Kahless the Unforgettable himself) upon which they are awarded with an "eternal battle against great enemies"

It seems from these descriptors that it is a place designed purely for warriors, to continue their battles indefinitely.

In particular, if they "were more trouble than they were worth" as Worf recalled, then it seems unlikely that Kahless would allow them to pass through.